# Splitting String With LastIndexOf() in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How to split A string By `LastIndexOf()` in VBA

I have a string which can have these kind of values

```
Dim input As String
   input =  "customName_D3"
   input =  "Custom_Name_D3"
   input =  "my_Custom_Name_D3"
```

like it can have many `"_"` in it but after last`"_"` it contains cell name
I want to split this string to get cell name and other remaning part as two different strings
something like

```
cellName = D3
remainingString = my_custom_Name
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Dim strInput As String
Dim strName As String
Dim strCellAddress As String
Dim iSplit As Integer

strInput = "my_Custom_Name_D3"

iSplit = InStrRev(strInput, "_")

strName = Left(strInput, iSplit - 1)
strCellAddress = Mid(strInput, iSplit + 1)

MsgBox "Name: " & vbTab & strName & vbCrLf & "Cell: " & vbTab & strCellAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
Public Function SplitAtLast(ByVal sText As String, ByVal sMatch As String, ByRef sLeft As String, ByRef sRight As String) As Integer
    Dim nIndex As Integer
    ' Search for sMatch within sText
    nIndex = InStrRev(sText, sMatch)

    If nIndex > 0 Then ' sMatch was found as nIndex'th character
        ' Save all chars before sMatch
        sLeft = Left$(sText, nIndex - 1)
        ' Save all chars after sMatch
        sRight = Mid$(sText, nIndex + Len(sMatch))
    Else ' sMatch was NOT found
        ' Save all chars into sLeft
        sLeft = sText
        sRight = ""
    End If
    ' Returns position of found match
    SplitAtLast = nIndex
End Function
```

To be called as

```
Dim sInput As String, sLeft As String, sRight As String, nIndex As Integer

sInput = "customName_D3"
nIndex = SplitAtLast(sInput, "_", sLeft, sRight)
MsgBox sInput & " : " & nIndex & ", <" & sLeft & ">, <" & sRight & ">"

sInput = "Custom_Name_D3"
nIndex = SplitAtLast(sInput, "_", sLeft, sRight)
MsgBox sInput & " : " & nIndex & ", <" & sLeft & ">, <" & sRight & ">"

sInput = "my_Custom_Name_D3"
nIndex = SplitAtLast(sInput, "_", sLeft, sRight)
MsgBox sInput & " : " & nIndex & ", <" & sLeft & ">, <" & sRight & ">"
```

Regards,
Daniele.